# Make a table listing all keys and values from a dictionary

Tags: swift, macos, nsmutabledictionary, cocoa-bindings

My AppDelegate contains a dictionary. I have an `NSDictionaryController` bound to `dict`. I then bind the 2 columns of an `NSTableView` to the Dictionary Controller:

- Column 1 (Key): Controller Key = `arrangedObjects`. Model Key Path = `key`
- Column 2 (Value): Controller Key = `arrangedObjects`. Model Key Path = `value`

But my table is blank. Any idea how's to correct this?

My code:

```
class AppDelegate {
    dynamic var dict = NSMutableDictionary()

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        dict.setValue(1, forKey: "One")
        dict.setValue(2, forKey: "Two")
    }
}
```

I also tried:

```
let newObject = dictController.newObject()
newObject.setKey("One")  // deprecated
newObject.setValue(1)    // deprecated
dictController.addObject(newObject)
```

But Xcode said `setKey` and `setValue` are deprecated in 10.10.3. How do I add an object to an `NSDictionaryController`? I'm running Mac OS X 10.11.4.

Comment: View based and cell based tableviews use different bindings. Is the tableview view based? Which bindings do you use?

Comment: I used cell-based tableview

Comment: How did you bind the tableview to the arraycontroller?

Answer (score 0):

The dictionary controller doesn't see the changes inside `dict`. You can solve this by first contructing the dictionary and then assigning to `dict`.

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    var tempDict = NSMutableDictionary()
    tempDict.setValue(1, forKey: "One")
    tempDict.setValue(2, forKey: "Two")
    dict = tempDict
}
```

Another solution is implementing key-value observer compliance.

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    willChangeValueForKey("dict")
    dict.setValue(1, forKey: "One")
    dict.setValue(2, forKey: "Two")
    didChangeValueForKey("dict")
}
```

Thanks to @Code Different for making me realize what the problem is.

Answer (score -1):

The little secret of `NSDictionaryController` is that you *must* specify a list of included keys via the `includedKeys` property. Otherwise, it will not have anything inside `arrangedObjects`. The easiest way is to bind the `includedKeys` to your `dict.keys` property.

In Interface Builder:

1. Select the Dictionary Controller, go to the Binding Inspector
2. For the **Included Keys** property: set Bind To = Delegate, Model Key Path = dict.keys

Programmatically:

```
dictController.bind(NSIncludedKeysBinding, toObject: self, withKeyPath: "dict.keys", options: nil)
```

Comment: "dict.keys" should be "dict.allKeys"?

Comment: `includedKeys` is an array containing the keys that are always present, even if they are not in the dictionary. Binding this property at the right time could be a workaround. Assigning the dictionary to the property again also fixes the problem.

Comment: You have such an interesting way to show appreciation! I was using Swift's native `Dictionary` rather than `NSMutableDictionary`